# What is the best way to check which object is returned from an API in typescript?

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

Stripe can return 3 different object types from as the customer.
I want the customer id which is what is normally returned.

What I have below is pretty ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
  const stripeCustomer: string | Stripe.Customer | Stripe.DeletedCustomer = checkoutSession.customer;
  let stripeCustomerId: string;

  if (stripeCustomer instanceof Object && "email" in stripeCustomer) {
    // customer is of type Stripe.Customer
      stripeCustomerId = stripeCustomer.id;
  } else if (typeof stripeCustomer === 'string') { 
    // customer is id
    stripeCustomerId = stripeCustomer;
  } else {
    // customer is of type Stripe.DeletedCustomer
    stripeCustomerId = null;
  }
```

Comment: If `customer` is a string, why are you using `customer.id`? Also, please use `typeof customer === "string"` and `typeof customer === "object"`.

Comment: @caTS Added a comment in the code. Because it is of type Stripe.Customer

Comment: I'm referring to your `else if` block.

Comment: Now your problem is gone, isn't it? No `any` needed.

Comment: I'd suggest checking `"id" in stripeCustomer` for the first type, since that is what you're after.

Comment: @caTS Sorry you are completely right. I had a typo in there. Have updated code with your method and it is working. Still a bit cumbersome though!

Comment: @NolanH but the StripeDeleted object has an id too.

Comment: It looks like you got the answer you wanted, but if you're after the `id` then yes, both Customer and DeletedCustomer have that so both should be acceptable. If you want to filter out deleted customers, I'd suggest checking `deleted` explicitly/separately.

Comment: As a side note: for more advanced cases, I highly recommend [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), which let your plug your own custom type-checking logic into the type system.

When they're true for an object, they inform the flow-sensitive typing that the object has the specified type:

```js
function isStripeCustomer(object: any): object is Stripe.Customer {
    return object instanceof Object 
       && "object" in object 
       && object.object === 'customer' 
       && !object.deleted
}

function isStripCustomerID(object: any): object is string {
    return typeof object === "string"
}

function isStripeDeletedCustomer(object: any): object is Stripe.DeletedCustomer {
    return object instanceof Object
       && "object" in object 
       && object.object === 'customer' 
       && object.deleted
}

const customer: string | Stripe.Customer | Stripe.DeletedCustomer = checkoutSession.customer;

let stripeCustomerId: string | null

if (isStripeCustomer(customer)) {
    stripeCustomerId = customer.id
} else if (isStripCustomerID(customer)) { 
    stripeCustomerId = customer;
} else if (isStripeDeletedCustomer(customer) {
    stripeCustomerId = null;
} else {
    // It was none of the known types. Perhaps a new type of result was
    // add in a future version of their API?

}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry! I had a typo in the code. Have edited above. it should be "customer" not "(customer as any).id"

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you could run your eye over it to confirm it looks ok I will accept as the answer.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the edit! By the way, it might be reasonable to implement `isStripeDeletedCustomer` as `isStripeCustomer(object) && object.deleted`

Comment: Ah nevermind, because `isStripeCustomer` checks for `object.deleted`. You could still extract a function from both, with the checks that they share in common (perhaps `isStripeAnyCustomer`)

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept you use is the right one. You can enhance it with typeguards to make it type-safe and allow to identify issues at compile-time:

```js
interface Customer {
    id: string;
}

type CustomerResponse = Customer | string | null;

function isCustomerObject(customer: CustomerResponse): customer is Customer {
    return customer != null && typeof customer === "object" && customer.id != null;
}

function isString(str: CustomerResponse): str is string {
    return typeof str === "string";
}

function identify(obj: Customer | string | null) {
    if (isCustomerObject(obj)) {
        console.log(obj, "is a customer with ID", obj.id);
    } else if (isString(obj)) {
        console.log(obj, "is a string with value", obj);
    } else {
        console.log(obj, "is null");
    }
}

const customerObject: Customer = {
    id: "123"
};


identify(customerObject);
identify("123");
identify(null);
```

See [the same code on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwChlzlgATALmWylAHMBuEgXxJLAE8AHFBmz5oAJQiY+OEJhQBeNFlwEoyAD70wjEE3XIQ6ADaG2JGOhAIwwaZUxDl0APIAjAFYQrACgRKRUOgd-cUlpWQBKOl9hFTtFGMJSCmQoCDB0KBBkaMdVAEIFA2NkADIS5F4BHBhsv1i5BuQAIhx3TzAm0vKc-wA6amQC-SMTDi5zS2tbYEwAZS1mLwZAurEJKRkISM1VGZ3mYjIKVPTMiv4Iap3kRqaGZia2TjMLKxss6ghwYBgeL1a3CsEqoNPcdHoioZwodkj9kF4ZkEVK4PN4AeFoUlkhQEGEcIYIL1DDgmP93AAaZp7OC1YHIADuwDAAAtkABJAAiTUpAP6VHCbGS7GQEEMskoNQRcwWOjJbgxMOx5FxMnxhOJpIBlKa1P24MZLOQADc4IZ0BBuch0YKKMLReKsUqVZg1USSXLtXtIU0BUdyJxns6wLTcij2kDcjdFeRqHQmgBGABMAGYmhxTCRPt9fj5VlAw1ZfVnrDmEymfWxiz8-pCBUA).